# Styled components in a hoc react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am having two issues with using styled components in a hoc wrapper in react.

1. The component is rendered, but not with the background color.
2. The ComponentWithAddedColors is not valid typescript. Don't know why.

Anyone who can help with this?

```
interface IProps {
  id: string;
  left: number;
  top: number;
}

export const Node: React.FC<IProps> = ({ id, left, top }) => {
  return (
    <Container left={left} top={top}>
      {id}
    </Container>
  );
};

function withColors<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
  const bg = "hotpink";
  const ComponentWithAddedColors = styled(Component)`
    ${bg && `background: ${bg};`}
  `;
  const result: React.FC<T> = (props) => (
    <ComponentWithAddedColors {...props} />
  );
  return result;
}

const DraggableNode = withColors(Node);
export default DraggableNode;
```

I have made a code sandbox to illustrate the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-hoc-xgduo?file=/src/Components/Node/Node.tsx

Comment: This is because that `styled` function accepts only styled component - means, a component which created by `styled` just like in [their exampe](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles). See this: https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-hoc-forked-wjb99?file=/src/Components/Node/Node.tsx

Comment: @MoshFeu Thank you for the feedback. Do you know why the typescript error happens also?

Comment: @MoshFeu I just checked the type definition file for styled. It does accept an JSX.IntrinsicElements as parameter. 
The problem was that the described at the bottom of the documentation:

"However, wrapping A in a styled() factory makes it eligible for interpolation -- just make sure the wrapped component passes along className."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Style Errors Explained

@Mosh Feu's comment pointed me in the right direction.

You can add styles [to an already styled component](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles) and you can add styles [to a custom component](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component), but those two things work differently.  You have a chain that goes through both types, so things are getting lost.

When you call `withColors(Node)` what this is doing is passing a generated `className` prop to `Node`.  But your custom component `Node` never does anything with this prop, so the style is never applied.

> The styled method works perfectly on all of your own or any third-party component, as long as they attach the passed className prop to a DOM element.

#### Style Errors Fixed

If we edit `Node` to use this `className`, we get the color!

```
export const Node: React.FC<IProps & {className?: string}> = ({ id, left, top, className}) => {
  return (
    <Container left={left} top={top} className={className}>
      {id}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

#### TS Errors Explained

As far as the typescript errors are concerned, you're getting an error about assigning your props `T` to the props of a styled component (`ComponentWithAddedColors`), which shows up as a bunch of crazy nonsense:

> (props: (Pick<Pick<(PropsWithoutRef & RefAttributes<Component<T, any, any>>) | (PropsWithRef<PropsWithChildren> & {}), Exclude<...> | ... 1 more ... | Exclude<...>> & Partial<...>, Exclude<...> | ... 1 more ... | Exclude<...>> & { ...; } & { ...; }) | (Pick<...> & ... 2 more ... & { ...; })): ReactElement<...>

This is mainly because of ref forwarding through the `ForwardRefExoticComponent` type.

But we can work backwards to get the expected props type from the component type using a utility type:

```
type PropsOf<T> = T extends React.ComponentType<infer P> ? P : never;
```

So `ComponentWithAddedColors` has props `PropsOf<typeof ComponentWithAddedColors>`.  We could use that, but we also know that `ComponentWithAddedColors` has type `StyledComponent<React.ComponentType<T>, any, {}, never>`, so we can go back a step further:

```
type StyledProps<InitialProps> = PropsOf<StyledComponent<React.ComponentType<InitialProps>, any, {}, never>>
```

So `ComponentWithAddedColors` has props `StyledProps<T>`.

#### TS Errors Fixed

That said, **all of this is unnecessary**, at least in the example you've shown.  You are passing all of the props of `ComponentWithAddedColors` through to `ComponentWithAddedColors`, so `result` is the same thing as the component itself.  Just return it directly.

```
function withColors<T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
  const bg = "hotpink";
  return styled(Component)`
    ${bg && `background: ${bg};`}
  `;
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: One greedy bonus question. When using the wrapper with a forwardRef, something seems to go wrong.
https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-hoc-dragndrop-stackoverflow-zlulr?file=/src/Components/Node/DraggableNode.tsx