# Extending / Overwriting styles of an imported React Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have two components, I have simplified the code here for brevity...
The problem is, when I import ComponentB to use as a child of ComponentA, I cannot seem to change ComponentB's styling.

I am using styled components FYI.

Example:
In ComponentA, I am importing ComponentB. ComponentB is a stand alone component that has its own styling and logic encapsulated. I need to overwrite / extend some ComponentB styling when it is being used in ComponentA.

Here is a code example:

```
// ComponentB
import React from "react";
import * as S from "./ComponentB.styles"; // styled components

export function ComponentB() {
  return (
    <S.Container>
      <S.Content
        {...props}
      />
    </S.Container>
  )
}
```

```
// ComponentA file
import React from "react";
import { ComponentB } from "./ComponentB";
import * as S from "./ComponentA.styles"; // styled components

export function ComponentA() {
  return (
    <S.Container>
      <S.Content
        <ComponentB {...props} /> // I need to use ComponentB but change its styling
      />
    </S.Container>
  )
}
```

**How can I use ComponentB as a child of ComponentA but change some of its styling?**

Comment: Does the first part of this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64599361/10431574 
 You need to make `ComponentB` accept a `className` and/or `style` prop and pass it through to the DOM.  Either on `S.Container` or on `S.Content`?  Or maybe it should accept props like `containerStyle` and `contentStyle` to do both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ComponentB` doesn't take any props, so anything that you pass to it is just going to be ignored completely.  You need to edit your components such that some styling prop can go all the way through to the DOM.

It is up to you *how* you want to implement overriding the styles.  Is it a `className` or a `CSSProperties` object?  Do styles apply to `S.Container`, to `S.Content`, or can you style both through separate props with names like `containerStyle` and `contentStyle`?

You can wrap the entire `ComponentB` in a `styled(ComponentB)` declaration and what this does is create a `className` prop with the correct styles ([docs link](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component)).  In order for this to work, your `ComponentB` must take this `className` and pass it along such that it eventually gets attached to the DOM.

Comment: Hi Linda, thanks so much for the comprehensive answer. I think I understand your suggestions, I like the idea of passing a className prop to (for example) S.Container, and adding some additional styles. I understand that this className would travel through to the DOM too. What I don't understand is where I would apply those styles, are you suggesting as a nested stlye in ComponentA styled-componenets? eg: CompA Container= styled` .className { width: 100%}`;?

Comment: I think I would do it like `StyledCompB = styled(ComponentB)'{ width: 100%}'`.  `ComponentA` would then use `StyledCompB` instead of `ComponentB`.  In order for that syntax to work, `ComponentB` becomes something like `function ComponentB({className, ...props}) { return (<S.Container className={className}><S.Content {...props} /></S.Container>); }` I think that works?  I've just realized that both your components were using `{...props}` but were not actually taking any props in the function arguments, so that's a mistake.

Comment: Hi again, yes, that was it! I get it now. Actually I had read about styled-component {className} before, but I actually didn't understand that this is what it was used for and how it worked. I understand a little better now, and this fixed my particular problem. 
Thanks again for your help and your explanation, it is much appreciated.
PS: yes, in my example I accidentally passed the props, that was a mistake.